# How do I call a function that I have defined in an extension on a button?

Tags: swift, uibutton, extension-methods

I have written the following function into my UIButton extension:

```
extension UIButton {
func detail(_ font: String, _ fontSize: CGFloat, _ cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: font, size: fontSize)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        return button
    }
}
```

However, when I try to call this function in my viewDidLoad(), I get the following error:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(theButton)
        theButton.detail("Avenir", 50, 12) // ERROR: Result of call to 'detail' is unused
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is error because your function has return value. Change your code to:

```
let resultButton = UIButton()
resultButton = theButton.detail("Avenir", 50, 12)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you, unfortunately that did not resolve the issue. My code does not need to have a return value per se, do you have any suggestion about changing my extension method such that the code in my viewDidLoad() is actually correct?

Edit: Sorry, my mistake, your code helped, thank you!